# Get historical data using Instagram API endpoints.

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api, endpoint

I am trying to fetch data using the Instagram API endpoints. Steps that I have followed 
1. Register the client app.
2. Got the access token.
3. I am using this access token through out the url endpoints.
Ex. to get the data for `recent media` I am using this url endpoint: `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`

However as I am in Sandbox mode, as per the documentation I get only the recent **20 media**. Whereas my account contains in total **291 media**. 
Problems that I am facing:

1. Not able to get `next_url` in the `pagination`part.
2. Usage of `min_id` and `max_id` in the url does not respond to any changes in the output or the data i.e fetched (Still get only **20 records/media**)

Ex: `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token=XXXXXX&min_id=xxxxxx_xxxxx&max_id=xxxxxxx_xxxxxxx`

**Can anybody provide a solution as to how exactly I should get all of my historical data ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in the sandbox mode so there's no way to achieve what you're trying to do before your app has been reviewed and approved (and gone live). From [Instagram API documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/):

> After your app has been reviewed and approved, you are ready to make it available to the general public. To switch your client from sandbox to live mode, you can use the button on the top section of the configuration screen for your app. When you are live, any Instagram user will be able to authorize your app, but you will have access only to the permissions that you were granted during the review.

Comment: does this mean that if the app is approved, I'll be able to fetch my entire required data and not only the recent '20 media' ??

Comment: Yes, the sandbox is restricting you to the 20 recent posts by the selected user. When your app is live, you can get all the posts in batches of 20.

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe you should try this library that allows you to scrape public info withou auth (client_id or access_token): https://github.com/raiym/instagram-php-scraper

```
$medias = Instagram::getMedias('kevin', 150);
```